# Why does swapping the template parameters in this code fix the error?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code gives out a no matching function error

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std;
template<class T, class U>
void fn (T t) {
    cout<<t<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    fn<int>(1);
    return 0;
}


C:\Users\tegra\Desktop\test.cpp||In function 'int main(int, const char**)':|
C:\Users\tegra\Desktop\test.cpp|9|error: no matching function for call to 'fn(int)'|
C:\Users\tegra\Desktop\test.cpp|9|note: candidate is:|
C:\Users\tegra\Desktop\test.cpp|4|note: template<class T, class U> void fn(T)|
C:\Users\tegra\Desktop\test.cpp|4|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Users\tegra\Desktop\test.cpp|9|note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'U'|
```

however, If you swap the template parameters like this, the error goes away

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std;
template<class U, class T>
void fn (T t) {
    cout<<t<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    fn<int>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`T` is deducible from the argument in the call. `U` is not.

When you write `fn<int>`, you are explicitly specifying the first parameter to be `int`. If `U` is the first parameter, there is no problem because `T` can be deduced. If `T` is first, though, the compiler doesn't know what `U` should be.

Comment: Exactly! Try making changing only "fn(T t)" to "fn(U t)" in your code, it will work.